# Как выдать роль в discord.py

Tags: python, discord

Коротко надо чтобы роль выдавалась по имени из базы данных, но это не получается реализовать. Ошибок нет, просто ничего не происходит.

```
@commands.cooldown(1, 10, commands.BucketType.user)
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role(t_slave_role)
async def rising(ctx):
    if ctx.author.id in banned:
        await channel.send(f"**{ctx.author}** соси ты в бане")
    else:
        channel = bot.get_channel(1198294998412705913) # ID Канала где игра
        slave_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=1198295390252974211) #Роль - раб
        clear_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=1198295666410135572) #Роль - Свобоный человек
        get_slave_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=1198295566787027004) #Роль - Рабовладелец

        if random.random() < 0.9:
            await channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(description=f'Восстание прошло успешно!', colour=discord.Color.green()))
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM slaves")
            for slaves in cursor.fetchall():
                for row in cursor.execute(f"SELECT id_slaveget, name_slaveget FROM slaves WHERE id_slave = {slaves[1]}"):
                    print(slaves[0], slaves[1], row[1], row[0])
                    cursor.execute(f"UPDATE users SET cash = cash / 5 WHERE id = {row[0]}")
                    cursor.execute(f"UPDATE users SET earning = earning / 5 WHERE id = {slaves[1]}")
                    cursor.execute(f"UPDATE users SET updates = updates * 5 WHERE id = {slaves[1]}")
                    await slaves[0].add_roles(clear_role) #РОЛИ НЕ СНИМАЮТСЯ
                    await row[1].add_roles(clear_role)
                    await slaves[0].remove_roles(slave_role)
                    await row[1].remove_roles(get_slave_role)
                    print(slaves[0], slaves[1], row[1], row[0])
                    cursor.execute(f"DELETE FROM slaves WHERE id_slave = {slaves[1]}")        
        else:
            await channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(description=f'**{ctx.author}**, что-то пошло не по плану', colour=discord.Color.red()))
        connection.commit()
```